# How to install ubuntu 13.04 on to a usb

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install ubuntu 13.04 to a 32gb usb stick so I can bring It to and from school. I've install about three time now using the something else install method And every time I install it says something like this "Installation complete please restart your computer". When i restart the computer and hold down alt (Due to the fact that I'm on mac) The usb doesn't show up as a bootable thing. When i go to reinstall it to the usb useing a cd it says that it is installed on it. So I want to know how to fix this

NOTE
(I don't want the iso on the usb thats on the cd. I want the os on the USB so i can bring to and from school)

computer specs for home and school they are macs

if they were pc this would be SOOO much easier saying how I've installed it on pc before but not mac and a usb together

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `sudo dd if=/path/to/file.iso of=/path/to/usb/device bs=1M`

/path/to/usb/device can be seen by using this command in terminal: `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: Well Thats to put the iso on the computer to start the install but i all ready have that on the cd what i want to do is install the os from the cd to the usb so i can bring from school and back

Comment: Then maybe you can use Startup Disk Creator from Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Bootable USB stick on Windows with http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

Bootable USB stick on Linux with apt://usb-creator-gtk

Answer (score 0):

unetbootin

UNetbootin allows you to create bootable Live USB drives for Ubuntu, Fedora, and other Linux distributions without burning a CD, you can find it in your software centre